# Puppeteer - как получить доступ к глобальному объекту Window?

Tags: puppeteer

собственно сам вопрос: как получить доступ к глобальному объекту Window в Puppeteer?
на сайте крутится JS при выполнении создается объект Scoreboard.
В браузере легко получить к нему доступ через window.Scoreboard
Как к нему же получить доступ через Puppeteer?

Answer (score 1):

Puppeteer может передавать между контекстом Node.js и браузерным контекстом два типа данных: сериализируемые данные (те, которые поддерживаются JSON) и идентификаторы объектов чужого контекста (так называемые `JSHandle` и `ElementHandle`).

Поэтому у вас два выхода: или полностью поместить весь код работы с объектом `window` в браузерную функцию, выполнить её при помощи `page.evaluate()` и вернуть конечные сериализируемые данные.

Или получить идентификатор объекта `window` (например, при помощи `page.evaluateHandle()`) и взаимодействовать с ним при помощи API, предоставляемого классами `JSHandle` и `ElementHandle` — но это API сравнительно трудоёмкое. Вы не сможете оперировать привычными DOM методами и свойствами в контексте Node.js, нужно будет всё время посылать и принимать запросы в контекст и из контекста браузера.

Comment: Спасибо! я пытался сделать как раз через evaluate. но сам себе оказался злым буратино - запрашивал window объект не проверив, что страница полностью загрузилась и скрипт отработал (т.е. объект создался...)